# Calculating the limit of the sequence $a_n=(2n+3)^\frac{1}{n}$ without using calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Calculating the limit of the sequence $a_n=(2n+3)^\frac{1}{n}$ without using calculus. I know that $a_n\to 1$, but I found it using calculus. However, this is an example for a real analysis course and so I need to understand how to calculate (not prove) the limit with only tools we have developed.

Comment: Since the definition of "limit" is pretty much the starting point for any real calculus course, calculating limits without calculus seems like a contradiction. Perhaps you could tell us what tools "we have developed" so that there's some hope of our not wasting our time trying to guess.

Comment: Hint: using derivatives are not the only way to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2n+3)}{n}=0$. You can, for example, show that $\ln(2n+3)<\sqrt{n}$ or equivalently $2n+3<e^{\sqrt n}$ for $n\ge 100$ using induction, for example.

Comment: If you want to calculate, not prove it, you can just compute the value of the sequence at some large value of $n$. For example, $a_{100} = 1.054...$, $a_{1000}=1.0076$

Comment: I wasn't trying to be snarky -- I meant what I said. I consider using the definition of limit to be "using calculus", and you can, after all, work out this limit direct from the definition, albeit with considerable difficulty. I also meant the other half: you can't expect us to know what tools your particular analysis course has developed, and if you don't tell us that, we're just gonna be shooting in the dark, wasting our time. Instead, you should help yourself get useful answers by writing a better question. Click on "edit" below your question to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two simple results $$a^{1/n}\to 1,a>0,n^{1/n}\to 1$$ as $n\to\infty $. These results are famous and not difficult to prove, but in case you are unaware here goes the proof.

For the first one note that the result holds trivially if $a=1$. If $a>1$ then $a^{1/n}>1$ and hence $a_n=a^{1/n}-1>0$ and we have $$a=(1+a_n) ^n>1+na_n,n>1$$ via binomial theorem. Therefore we have $$0<a_n<\frac{a-1}{n},n>1$$ Applying squeeze theorem we see that $a_n\to 0$ and hence $a^{1/n}=1+a_n\to 1$.

If $0<a<1$ then we have $b=1/a>1$ and hence $b^{1/n}\to 1$ and $a^{1/n}=1/b^{1/n}\to 1$ and hence the first result is established.

For second result we use the same technique by writing $b_n=n^{1/n}-1$ and then $b_n>0$ for $n>2$. And we have $$n=(1+b_n) ^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}b_n^2,n>2$$ via binomial theorem. Thus $$0<b_n<\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}},n>2$$ and our job is complete via Squeeze thoerem.

Once these results are established, we can apply squeeze theorem to the current question. If $n>3$ then we have $$(2n)^{1/n}<(2n+3)^{1/n}<(3n)^{1/n}$$ and using squeeze theorem we see that the desired limit is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(2n+3)^{1/n}=1+R(n).$ We have $R(n)>0$ for $n>0.$ For $n\geq 2,$ by the Binomial Theorem we have $$2n+3=(1+R(n))^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom {n}{j}R(n)^j>$$ $$>\binom {n}{2}R(n)^2=\frac {n^2-n}{2}R(n)^2.$$ So for $n\geq 2$ we have $$\sqrt  {\frac {4n+6}{n^2-n}}>R(n)>0.$$

BTW. If $n\geq 2$ then $\frac {4n+6}{n^2-n}=$ $\frac {(4n-4)+10}{n^2-n}=$ $\frac {4}{n}+\frac {10}{n(n-1)}\leq$ $ \frac {4}{n}+\frac {10}{n}=$ $\frac {14}{n}.$

Comment: You used the binomial directly! +1 my answer uses the same idea in steps and takes a bit longer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Similarly, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial with positive leading co-efficient and degree $d $, and if $p(n)^{1/n}=1+R(n)$ when $p(n)>0,$ then for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $p(n)>\binom {n}{d+1}R(n)^{d+1}>0,$ and since $\binom {n}{d+1}$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $d+1,$ therefore $R(n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Not really a detailed proof here. 
Here's one way I think.
You can rewrite $a_n$ as
$$
a_n= (2n+3)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}n^{1/n}\left(1+\frac{3}{2n}\right)^{1/n}= e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln 2}e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln n}e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{3}{2n}\right)}
$$
Now use the facts (proved elsewhere) that the limit of a product of functions is the product of the limits, i.e given $F=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n$ and $G=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g_n$, one gets $FG= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_ng_n$ and the limit of composite functions $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(a_n)=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n)$.

Hence, you now have to find
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln 2}&=e^0=1\\
 \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln n} &=e^0=1\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{3}{2n}\right)}&= e^0=1
\end{align}
Note that you can use in the last line above the inequality
$$
0<\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{3}{2n}\right)<\frac{3}{2n^2}
$$
valid for any $n>0$.
Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=1$.